# React Router + Redux Form + Edit/New Component == Fail

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

I'm trying to create a React component that is capable either to create or edit an existing item in my database. Everything is working fine, except one thing: when I call a route `new` from the `edit` route (the same component with different behavior), React simply keeps the previous form state and I can't see a new form with empty data. It only works when I call the `new` route from somewhere else.

Possible routes:

- `/bastions/new` - Renders the component with no data
- `/bastions/:id` - Renders the component with an existing data

Is this problem familiar for someone?

Just some code to make things cleaner (with the most relevant peaces):

Thanks in advance.

```
class BastionForm extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {      
        if(this.props.bastion.number) {      
            this.props.fetchBastion(this.props.params.number);
        }
    }

    renderField({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
        return (
            <FormGroup controlId={label} {...validation}>
                <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
                <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this)) }>
                <h3>Create a new Bastion</h3>

                <Field name="sample" type="text" component={this.renderField} />

                <ButtonToolbar>
                    <Button bsStyle="primary" disabled={submitting}>Submit</Button>
                </ButtonToolbar>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

BastionForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'BastionForm',
    enableReinitialize: true
})(BastionForm);

BastionForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: state.bastions.bastion
    }), { fetchBastion }
)(BastionForm);

export default BastionForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is only invoked once before mounting occurs. Since `/bastions/new` and `/bastions/:id` are actually referring to the same route, `BastionForm` will not be unmounted when your path changes from `/bastions/:id` to `/bastions/new`. So you can decide whether showing an existed data or showing with no data through changing the state of `BastionForm`(dispatch an action). Then handle the props change in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Thank you for the support and sorry the delay for answering. You're right! componentWillReceiveProps solved the problem. But I'm wondering something about what you said, that both /bastions/:id and /bastions/new are referred to the same route, and I guess it's because the first one has a URL param (id) and can be replaced by any string (like "new" in this case) and that's why BastionForm wouldn't be unmounted. But even changing completely the routes it didn't work. Is this behavior has something to do with redux and react-router unsync state?

Comment: If the two routes refer to the same component(e.g.`BastionForm`), it still won't recreate the component, even if the two routes are completely different. Besides, if the answer is right, please mark it accepted to make it obvious for other guys encountering the same question.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks for replying!